# How to create a redmine webapp for tomcat

Tags: tomcat, redmine

Looking around the internet, i can't find new documentation on how to package redmine as a .war webapp on tomcat.

When i tried packaging redmine to a .war file, i came across an incompatibility between warbler that depends on rubyzip version < 1.4 and redmine, that requires rubyzip version 2.3. Is there a way around that?

Edit: Redmine version 4.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular change to relax the rubyzip dependency was already committed to the warbler repository with https://github.com/jruby/warbler/pull/491. However, there is not yet a new release of the gem with this fix.

It appears that the maintainers of the warbler gem are currently in the process of modernizing the gem and other ecosystem dependencies. Thus, things are currently in flux and there is likely no single best way to resolve this now for you.

In any case, Redmine (and some of its dependencies) does not officially support JRuby. As such, even if you get warbler to run, you will likely observe other issues along the way which might be dealbreakers. Accordingly, I'd rather recommend to use an application server with MRI Ruby (i.e. the "classic" Ruby) rather than JRuby and warbler for your Redmine installation.